Youtube Data API - Get private and unlisted Playlists
In a Laravel app, I am trying to get the playlists associated to my YouTube channel.
These playlists can be either public, private or unlisted.
I can retrieve public playlists but I am struggling to get the unlisted and private ones, even with oAuth configured.
Here is my code
public function getPlaylist()
    {

        $client = new Client();
        $client->setLogger(new \Monolog\Logger('google-api'));
        $client->setApplicationName('Playlists');


        $client->setAuthConfig(base_path('youtube.json'));

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        if (Session::has('google_oauth_token')) {
            $client->setAccessToken(Session::get('google_oauth_token'));
        }

        $service = new YouTube($client);

        $queryParams = [
            'channelId' => config('scraper.channelId'),
            'maxResults' => 50,
            'mine' => 1,
        ];

        $response = $service->playlists->listPlaylists('snippet, contentDetails, status, id', $queryParams);


        dd($response);
    }

I get the following error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Incompatible parameters specified in the request: channelId, mine",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Incompatible parameters specified in the request: channelId, mine",
                "domain": "youtube.parameter",
                "reason": "incompatibleParameters",
                "location": "parameters.",
                "locationType": "other"
            }
        ]
    }
}

When I remove the mine parameter. I get the public playlists.
If I keep the mine parameter and remove the channelId, I get this error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Channel not found.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Channel not found.",
                "domain": "youtube.playlist",
                "reason": "channelNotFound",
                "location": "channelId",
                "locationType": "parameter"
            }
        ]
    }
}

What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible to get private and unlisted playlists?
Thank you for your assistance on this

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list APIs Explorer shows that with Google OAuth 2.0 and only setting mine to True we can retrieve both Unlisted and Private playlists.
